# Media Queries in JavaScript - How to add Breakpoints and change "slidesPerView" in "Swiper" Slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm using the this script:

```
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 50,
});
```

I would like the "slidesPerView: 3" to change to "slidesPerView: 2" when the screen width gets smaller then 1000px, and to "slidesPerView: 1" when screen width gets smaller then 500px.

As I know nothing of javascript syntax, please help me out by writing the full code.

Thanks you for your help.

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for your replies.

I still can't get it to work though...

Bellow is the complete script.

What am I doing wrong???

```
var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper2', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    freeMode: true,
    loop: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    breakpoints: {
        // when window width is <= 499px
        499: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 30
        },
        // when window width is <= 999px
        999: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 40
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Checking the DOC (briefly...), you should use `breakpoints` option. See it here: http://idangero.us/swiper/api/

Comment: Thank you for calling my attention to that, I still can't get it work though, will you please see my updated code? Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated by `A Wolff`, check the documentation first and use the `breakpoints` method, something like:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // Default parameters
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    // Responsive breakpoints
    breakpoints: {
        // when window width is <= 499px
        499: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 50
        },
        // when window width is <= 999px
        999: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetweenSlides: 50
        }
    }
});
```

Since it's a `less than or equal to` equation, just take off a pixel so once it's under 500px (aka 499px), readjust and same for 1000.

I left the `spaceBetweenSlides` in there for you to mess with, but if you want to just keep it at `50`, feel free to remove them from the `breakpoints`.

[Swiper API Docs](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/)

**EDIT**

After reviewing the site, there are a few things that need to be changed:

- You need to call the Swiper JS file in the `head` of the document,
  instead of inline with both slideshows (only need to call it once,
  put it below the jQuery script tag)
- Can't have the same class name on both slides because it will then attach the first set of rules to both sliders
- Make sure the document is ready before manipulating the `DOM`, removing the `script` tags from by the sliders and put this in the `head`

Here's how I would set up the Swipers:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add this part below the jQuery script call -->
<script src="js/slideshow-swiper.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Once the DOM has loaded, attach the Swiper(s)
    $(function(){
        var swiper_banner = new Swiper('#slideshow_banner', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            loop: true
        });
        var swiper_services = new Swiper('#slideshow_services', {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 50,
            freeMode: true,
            loop: true,
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
            breakpoints: {
                // when window width is <= 499px
                499: {
                    slidesPerView: 1,
                    spaceBetweenSlides: 30
                },
                // when window width is <= 999px
                999: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetweenSlides: 40
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- Continue loading fonts, etc -->
```

Don't add the jQuery file in there twice, just putting it there for a reference point. Also both containers have the same ID and that's not valid HTML, so change the ID's and attach the Swipers that way. So now your containers would be something like:

```
<div class="swiper-container" id="slideshow_banner"><!-- Code --></div>
...
<div class="swiper-container" id="slideshow_services"><!-- Code --></div>
```

Once you update that, it should fix itself, however I can't test it live on your site so let me know once you've updated the code and I'll take a look.

**EDIT 1.1**

It seems the `breakpoints` method is a real 'breakpoint' in the function as it has a weird way of handling the `Object` that is passed and therefore gives varied results across browsers, so with the use of the `onResize()` method and some JS, let's fix that:

```
<script>
    // Once the DOM has loaded, attach the Swiper(s)
    $(function(){
        var swiper_banner = new Swiper('#slideshow_banner', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            loop: true
        });
        var swiper_services = new Swiper('#slideshow_services', {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 50,
            freeMode: true,
            loop: true,
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev'
        });
        // Breakpoints
        $(window).on('resize', function(){
            var width = $(window).width();
            if(width < 1000 && width >= 500) {
                swiper_services.params.slidesPerView = 2;
                swiper_services.params.spaceBetween = 40;
            } else if(width < 500) {
                swiper_services.params.slidesPerView = 1;
                swiper_services.params.spaceBetween = 30;
            } else {
                swiper_services.params.slidesPerView = 3;
                swiper_services.params.spaceBetween = 50;
            }
            swiper_services.onResize();
        }).resize();    
    });
</script>
```

There, that should do it. I tested that on Chrome, FF, and IE9+ and it was running fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. That's exactly what I'm after, but It doesn't seem to work. Please take a look at my updated code, can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Could you include the `HTML` file it's being called from? Or maybe a live link via [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pen/).

Comment: I can't get it to work properly in JSFiddle or CodePen, have no idea why, but here's a [**link**](http://www.biolimpe.pt/teste/index.htm) to my project... Appreciate you helping with this. The issue is with the second slideshow further down the page...

Comment: @DavidMartins alright, here's a few things you're gonna want to change, check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your trouble. I've updated the code, I believe I did everything exactly as you said but maybe I've missed something because I still see three slides no matter what. Please [**take a look**](http://www.biolimpe.pt/teste/index.htm)

Comment: Alright, after some further research and testing on my own end (I tested in Chrome, FF, and IE 9+), it seems the `breakpoints` method doesn't really work yet because of the way it handles the `Object`; but I just forced a little hack with JavaScript, check my answer again @DavidMartins .

Comment: Thank you once again for your time and effort. I've updated the code in the test page with your new approach as you can see. For sake of testing, as I still have other responsive issues I need to address, I've changed the breakpoints to 1300px and 1000px. As you can see it does go down to two slides per view at 1300px which is great but it never gets to just one...

Comment: @DavidMartins whoops, logical error on my part, when running the `if/else`, if first checks if the width is under `1300` and moves from there, try changing the first if to: `if(width < 1300 && width >= 1000) {` that way it will move to the second condition once it's below `1000`.

Comment: Hurray! It works! Thank you so much for all your help. Best wishes.

Comment: It looks like the OP is using the breakpoints logic wrongly. Breakpoint of 499 doesn't mean less than or equal to, it's actually the opposite i.e, greater than or equal to 499. All those custom breakpoint logic isn't required, if you use the breakpoints properly. https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this example.

```
breakpoints: {
  // when window width is >= 320px
  320: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 20
  },
  // when window width is >= 480px
  480: {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30
  },
  // when window width is >= 640px
  640: {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 40
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The selected answer is wrong in the current version.

Answer (score 1):

You could use window.matchMedia() https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

```
 if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").matches) {
      /* the viewport is at least 1000 pixels wide */
    } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)").matches){
      /* the viewport is less than 999 pixels wide */
    } else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)").matches){
      /* the viewport is less than 500 pixels wide */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.matchMedia` lets you write media **queries** with the same syntax used in CSS. [This is supported by all major browsers with IE > 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia)

> I would like the "slidesPerView: 3" to change to "slidesPerView: 2" when the screen width gets smaller then 1000px, and to "slidesPerView: 1" when screen width gets smaller then 500px.

Here's how you'd do it with pure CSS :

```
/* means: if the viewport size is 501px wide or wider, and lower or equal to 999px... */
@media (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 999px) {

  /* then apply some CSS rules to selectors below : */
  .my-element {
    ...
  }
}
```

And the equivalent in Javascript :

```
/* first you need to check if window.matchMedia is supported by the current browser */
if ("matchMedia" in window) {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 999px)").matches) {
    // slidesPerView: 2
  } 
  else if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)").matches) {
    // slidesPerView: 1
  }
  else {
    // slidesPerView: 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've updated my question, and followed the instruction suggested by the documentation but no mater what there's always 3 slides, you can take a look at my project [**here**](http://www.biolimpe.pt/teste/index.htm). The issue is with the second slideshow down the page. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To update @faino's answer to be jQuery free

```
   let onresize = function (e) {
   let width = e.target.innerWidth;
        if (width < 500) {
            swiper_services.params.spaceBetween = 100;
        } else {
            swiper_services.params.spaceBetween = 50;
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
```